# How to access google scholar via Android Webview

Tags: android, android-webview, google-scholar

My current Android Application uses a WebView to allow users to search for Scientific Journals (articles).

When I try to browse to Google Scholar I receive a screen that says

```
We're Sorry... ...but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our user's we can't process your request right now.
```

What does "`automated query`" mean? My webView simply attempts to load the Scholar URL why do google users need protecting from that?

Does this mean that Google Scholar can never be accessed via an Android WebView?

Is there any way to access Google Scholar via an Android Webview?

Comment: Are you on AT&T network?

Comment: @fluffyBatman no I am not. Why does the network matter? Im just attempting to browse to the scholar home page via an Android WebView. I do not understand whats "automated" about that.

Comment: try to clear your webview cookies and try again

Comment: @KingofMasses this worked, once I cleared all my app data I was able to access Google Scholar

Comment: Happy to help mate :) Cheers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the cache and cookies for the webview and try again.

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);         
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();        
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
```

For Lollypop and above:

```
removeAllCookies(ValueCallback)
```

This topic is discussed [here in google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/PfocqGCwROg)

Note:

QS already fixed the problem with my comment, i written this answer to help some one who faces this issue.