# Android WebView not loading Blog

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, blogs, blogger

**Android WebView not loading Blog** - **in mobile data**; but the same works fine while using wifi broadband connection

For 1 year the same code works fine;only two days now this problem started 
Its shows

**err_name_not_resolved** - in mobile data(Airtel, Jio, Idea, etc)

**Same code works fine in Wifi Broadband(BSNL, India)**

```
 mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.not_webView);
     WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
     webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
     webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
     mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
     mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
     mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
     webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

     mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

         @Override
         public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
             //hide loading image
             findViewById(R.id.imageLoading).setVisibility(View.GONE);
             findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
             //show webview
             findViewById(R.id.not_webView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }

         @Override
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
             if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("abcd.blogspot.in")) {
                 return false;
             }

             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
             view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
             return true;
         }

     });
     mWebView.loadUrl("https://abcd.blogspot.in");
```

I tried facebook page url & other urls instead of blog; & it works fine...

Comment: try to clear your webview cookies and try again

Comment: How can we clear the webview cookies, can u give me a sample code

Comment: you can check it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45230679/3983054

Answer (score 0):

(First of all try removing the line for render quality (high.))

There are 3
possible things..
(Note: Check your url by putting it in browser)

1. Due to your access points..
2. Check the manifest for network realated permissions
3. Wait many times blogspot loads very slowly..

Comment: For last 3 months I used same code and my App works fine. The problem started last Saturday (22-july+2017

While manually typing the url direct in Chrome browser it works fine..in mobile data..but not working inside the app

How can we change the access point while we r using mobile data

Also Blog is loading with a reduction. Eg: I opened my FB page.. & click my blog page, now it's loading my blog page